# Source for UTM Zone File

Tags: data, utm

I'm looking for a complete, freely available file showing UTM Grid zones. Preferably *not* a simplified version, but one that shows the full grid zones and all 'exceptions' (e.g. in Northern Europe) - as per http://whatutmzoneamiin.blogspot.com/

Does anyone know where I can download such a file?

Comment: What file format are you looking for?  Its fairly simple to implement a LL -> UTM Zone algorithm, which can be used to generate the zones based on location, depending on how you want it displayed.

Comment: The calculation is at http://www.luomus.fi/english/botany/afe/map/utm.htm , but a shapefile would be nice...

Comment: I don't much care about format..I can convert from one to another... I realize I could write an algorithm, but it seems like someone must have already created a file..no sense reinventing the wheel!

Comment: The map at that blog is broken: "This map has been unpublished, changed location or is not currently available. "

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Will this do:
http://www.baruch.cuny.edu/geoportal/data/esri/world/utmzone.zip
I haven't taken a close look at it, but it looked like it has the exceptions on there.

Comment: Slightly updated link: http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/geoportal/data/esri/world/utmzone.zip

Answer (score 4):

Adding another just in case those links go stale: [Global UTM Zones Grid — EPDI | EnviroProjects Digital Initiative](http://www.enviroprojects.org/geospatial-services/gis-resources/global-utm-zones/view). It's CC licensed, and has the exceptions around Norway and Svalbard.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken. Here's an archival link for grid: http://archive.sustainableos.international/www.enviroprojects.org/geospatial-services/gis-resources/global-utm-zones/at_download/utm_final_zone.zip

Answer (score 1):

Shapefile

**world_utmzones.zip**

deadlink
was www.tzgisug.org/tikiwiki/tiki-list_file_gallery.php?galleryId=2

Comment: Thanks Mapperz. I've seen that file. However, if you notice, it doesn't have all of the 'exceptions' I mentioned. I'm looking for a full 'unsimplified' file.

Comment: @Mapperz Just FYI, the link you provided is now dead.

Comment: Try https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=715d4d6a36cc4b019bd84cb34ce37647 for UTM Zone and Time Zones