# Get XY coordinates in UTM from web-mercator where UTM zone is not known

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system, utm, measurements, web-mercator

How to get XY(northing/easting) coordinates in UTM  where data is WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere(WKID: 3857) coordinate system and UTM zone is unknown.
For e.g. India falls under multiple UTM zones and map is in Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere.
I am trying to replicate Google earth's UTM coordinate display using ArcGIS Javascript API.
Thanks.

Nagesh

Comment: Does http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/7532 answer your question? It explains where to obtain data describing the UTM zone boundaries.

Comment: Not sure if there is a better solution, but you can do the calculation manually with the formulas on this page http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/UsefulData/UTMFormulas.HTM actually http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/UsefulData/ConvertUTMNoOZ.HTM has the whole thing already in javascript, you may have to convert to WGS84 first though...

Answer (score 2):

This is how you change it to UTM, 
First you have yo change it to wgs, and then call the function to do the rest

```
  function showCoordinates(evt) {
     var wgs = webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint);
                var mp = evt.mapPoint;
                // Converting The WGS to UTM
                document.getElementById("utmCoordinates").innerHTML = myFunction(wgs.x, wgs.y);
                function myFunction(lan1, fi)

 {

                var a = 6378137.000;
                var b = 6356752.314;
                var f = (a - b) / a;
                var e2 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2)) / Math.pow(b, 2));
                var e = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2)) / Math.pow(a, 2));

                var zone;
                var lan0;
                if (lan1 > 0) {
                    var zone = 30 + Math.ceil(lan1 / 6);
                    lan0 = Math.floor(lan1 / 6) * 6 + 3;
                }
                else {
                    var zone = 30 - Math.floor(Math.abs(lan1) / 6);
                    lan0 = -Math.floor(Math.abs(lan1) / 6) * 6 - 3;
                }


                //-----------------------------------------------

                var lan = lan1 - lan0;
                lan = lan * Math.PI / 180;
                fi = fi * Math.PI / 180;
                var N = a / Math.pow(1 - Math.pow(e, 2) * Math.pow(Math.sin(fi), 2), 0.5);
                var M = a * (1 - Math.pow(e, 2)) / Math.pow((1 - (Math.pow(e, 2) * Math.pow(Math.sin(fi), 2))), (3 / 2));
                var t = Math.tan(fi);
                var p = N / M;

                //----------------------------------------------
                var k0 = 0.9996;

                var term1 = Math.pow(lan, 2) * p * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi), 2) / 2;
                var term2 = Math.pow(lan, 4) * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi), 4) * (4 * Math.pow(p, 3) * (1 - 6 * Math.pow(t, 2)) + Math.pow(p, 2) * (1 + 24 * Math.pow(t, 2)) - 4 * p * Math.pow(t, 2)) / 24;
                var term3 = Math.pow(lan, 6) * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi), 6) * (61 - 148 * Math.pow(t, 2) + 16 * Math.pow(t, 4)) / 720;

                var Kutm = k0 * (term1 + term2 + term3);


                //----------------------------------------------
                term1 = Math.pow(lan, 2) * p * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi), 2) * (p - Math.pow(t, 2)) / 6;
                term2 = Math.pow(lan, 4) * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi), 4) * (4 * Math.pow(p, 3) * (1 - 6 * Math.pow(t, 2)) + Math.pow(p, 2) * (1 + 8 * Math.pow(t, 2)) - Math.pow(p, 2) * Math.pow(t, 2) + Math.pow(t, 4)) / 120;
                term3 = Math.pow(lan, 6) * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi), 6) * (61 - 479 * Math.pow(t, 2) + 179 * Math.pow(t, 4) - Math.pow(t, 6)) / 5040;

                var Xutm = 500000 + k0 * lan * N * Math.cos(fi) * (1 + term1 + term2 + term3);

                //----------------------------------------------

                var A0 = 1 - 0.25 * Math.pow(e, 2) - 3 / 64 * Math.pow(e, 4) - 5 / 256 * Math.pow(e, 6);
                var A2 = 3 / 8 * (Math.pow(e, 2) + 0.25 * Math.pow(e, 4) + 15 / 128 * Math.pow(e, 6));
                var A4 = 15 / 256 * (Math.pow(e, 4) + 0.75 * Math.pow(e, 6));
                var A6 = 35 / 3072 * Math.pow(e, 6);

                var sfi = a * (A0 * fi - A2 * Math.sin(2 * fi) + A4 * Math.sin(4 * fi) - A6 * Math.sin(6 * fi));

                //----------------------------------------------

                term1 = Math.pow(lan, 2) * N * Math.sin(fi) * Math.cos(fi) / 2;
                term2 = Math.pow(lan, 4) * N * Math.sin(fi) * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi), 3) * (4 * Math.pow(p, 2) + p - Math.pow(t, 2)) / 24;
                term3 = Math.pow(lan, 6) * N * Math.sin(fi) * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi), 5) * (8 * Math.pow(p, 4) * (11 - 24 * Math.pow(t, 2)) - 28 * Math.pow(p, 3) * (1 - 6 * Math.pow(t, 2)) + Math.pow(p, 2) * (1 - 32 * Math.pow(t, 2)) - p * 2 * Math.pow(t, 2) + Math.pow(t, 4));
                var term4 = Math.pow(lan, 8) * N * Math.sin(fi) * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi), 7) * (1385 - 3111 * Math.pow(t, 2) + 543 * Math.pow(t, 4) - Math.pow(t, 6));

                var Yutm = k0 * (sfi + term1 + term2 + term3 + term4);
                UTMx = Xutm.toFixed(5);
                UTMy = Yutm.toFixed(5);
                return (Xutm.toFixed(5).toString() + "," + Yutm.toFixed(5).toString());

                //return Xutm.toString().concat(" ; " + Yutm.toString() + " " + zone.toString());
            }
```